# How to shorten adding to byte array?

Tags: python, numpy

```
packed_source_stream_offsets = bytearray()
for x in source_stream_offset:
    packed_source_stream_offsets += varint.encode(x)
```

Is there a way I can do this on fewer lines or make it more compact? I'm trying to make my code more compact, and I'm wondering if there's a shorter way of doing this.

Comment: What iare `source_stream_offset` and `varint` (their types)?

Comment: source_stream_offset is an ndarray of int32s and varint.encode() returns bytes.

Comment: `packed_source_stream_offset = bytearray.join((varint.encode(x) for x in source_stream_offset)))`

Answer (score 0):

It's always a bit difficult to answer when there is no reproducible code (e.g. not knowing what `source_stream_offset` is, or where `varint` comes from, but I think this should apply in general:

1. Instead of appending you can use an empty string or byte to `join` individual parts
2. You can map over the function rather than using an explicit value

That should yield something like:

```py
bytearray(b''.join(map(varint.encode, source_stream_offset)))
```

*Note*: If you're not comfortable with the `map` syntax, you can also use a list comprehension like:

```py
 bytearray(b''.join([varint.encode(x) for x in source_stream_offset]))
```

Comment: You can also use a generator expression instead of a list comprehension to avoid creating an intermediate list (just remove the square brackets).

Comment: Actually, list comprehensions are better for `''.join()`: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9061024